# angularjs md-tabs with multi line tab heading

Tags: angularjs

i have done a web module using angular material tab demos
and out put is like following
[image]

i want tabs heading(circled with black line) should be in more than one line

i tired everything but got nothing...please help

```html
 <md-tab label="MOBILIZATION SETTINGS" >
        <md-content class="md-padding tab-content" style="padding:0px;">            <!--in line css  -->
 <div class=" callout-elem-info ng-scope cntrl-div" >
 <div class="main-heading">
 <h2>Mobilization Settings</h2>
 <div class="add-button" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">ADD</div>
 </div>
 <div class="ElementsToBeAdd" ng-show="collapsed">
 <ul>
   <a href="#/da/clusterAndSubClusterInfo"> <li>
        CLuster and SubCluster
    </li></a>
    
    <a href="#/da/vehicleModelInfo"><li>
        Vehicle Model Info
    </li></a>
    
    <a href="#/da/reasonsOfNotInrestedInSmartShift"><li>
        Reasons Of Not Intrested In SamrtShift
    </li></a>
    
   <a href="#/da/reasonsOfLeavingCompitition"> <li>
       Reasons Of Leaving Compitition
    </li></a>
    
    <a href="#/da/reasonsLtOfNotReadyAsSmartShifter"> <li>
       Reasons Of Lt Not Ready To Operate As SmartShifter
    </li></a>
    
     <a href="#/da/reasonsFoOfNotReadyAsSmartShifter"> <li>
       Reasons Of Fo Not Ready To Operate As SmartShifter
    </li></a>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <!-- <div ng-cloak> -->
  <md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom style="height: 500px;">    <!--in line css  -->
      <md-tab label="Cluster And SubCluster" >
        <md-content class="md-padding tab-content">
         <!--  <h1 class="md-display-2">Cluster And SubCluater</h1> -->       
               <ul class="allClusterList" >
       <li ng-repeat="obj in allClusterList">
        <div class="div-in-li">
        <div class="clusterNameHeading"><h2>{{$index+1}}.</h2> <div class="clusterNameObj">{{obj.clusterName}}<div class="edit-button">
         <a style="color:white;" href="#/da/clusterAndSubClusterInfo/{{obj.clusterId}}">EDIT</a></div></div></div>        
        </div>            
       </li>
      </ul>
       
        </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Not Interested in SmartShift">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <!-- <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1> -->
          <ul class="allClusterList">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in notIntrestedInSmartShiftReasons">
     <div class="div-in-li">
       <div class="clusterNameHeading"><h2>{{$index+1}}.</h2> <div class="reasonNameObj">{{obj.reason}}<div class="edit-button">
       <a style="color:white;" href="#/da/reasonsOfNotInrestedInSmartShift/{{obj.id}}">EDIT</a></div></div></div>
     </div>    
   </li>
  </ul>
          </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Reasons Of Leaving Compitition">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
         <!--  <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1> -->
          <ul class="allClusterList">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in reasonsOfLeavingCompitition">
    <div class="div-in-li">
    <div class="clusterNameHeading"><h2>{{$index+1}}.</h2> <div class="reasonNameObj">{{obj.reason}}<div class="edit-button">
    <a style="color:white;" href="#/da/reasonsOfLeavingCompitition/{{obj.reasonId}}">EDIT</a></div></div></div>
    </div>

   </li>
  </ul>
          </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Vehicle Model Info">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <!-- <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1> -->
           <ul class="allClusterList">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in vehicleInfoList">
       <div class="div-in-li">
       <div class="clusterNameHeading"><h2>{{$index+1}}.</h2> <div class="vehicleModelNameObj">{{obj.modelName}}<div class="edit-button">
       <a style="color:white;" href="#/da/vehicleModelInfo/{{obj.vehicleModelId}}">EDIT</a></div></div></div>  
       </div>
    
   </li>
  </ul>
          </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      <md-tab label="Reasons Of Lt Not Ready To Operate As SmartShifter">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
         <!--  <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1> -->
          <ul class="allClusterList">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in reasonsOfNotReadyAsSmartShifter">
       <div class="div-in-li">
        <div class="clusterNameHeading"><h2>{{$index+1}}.</h2> <div class="reasonNameObj">{{obj.reason}}<div class="edit-button">
       <a style="color:white;" href="#/da/ReasonsOfLtNotReadyToOperateAsSmartShifter/{{obj.notReadyToOperateAsSmartShiftId}}">EDIT</a></div></div></div>
        
       </div>
    
   </li>
  </ul>
          </md-content>
      </md-tab>
      
       
       <md-tab label="Reasons Of Fo Not Ready To Operate As SmartShifter">
        <md-content class="md-padding">
          <!-- <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1> -->
          <ul class="allClusterList">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in reasonsOfFoNotReadyAsSmartShifter">
     <div class="div-in-li">
       <div class="clusterNameHeading"><h2>{{$index+1}}.</h2> <div class="reasonNameObj">{{obj.reason}}<div class="edit-button">
       <a style="color:white;" href="#/da/jobCreationCity/{{obj.id}}">EDIT</a></div></div></div>
     </div>    
   </li>
  </ul>
          </md-content>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
  </md-content>
<!-- </div> -->
 
 
 </div>
 </md-content>
 </md-tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<md-tab>
 <md-tab-label> 
  My Label HTML <!-- try your HTML here to make multi-line -->
 </md-tab-label>
 <md-tab-body> <!-- this tag is now required -->
  My Body HTML
 </md-tab-body>
</md-tab>
```